# Upgrading from rails 4.2.0 to 5.0.0 and Ruby from 2.2.4 to 2.5.8 - Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Sub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, upgrade, circular-dependency

I finally got rails 5 and Ruby 2.5.8 to play nicely with each other.

Migrations are up to date and work well.

I'm using elasticsearch for search and memcache for caching - both work (or at least I think they do).

I've added the ApplicationRecord class to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and updated all of my classes to inherit from ApplicationRecord.

I have disabled the attr_accessible gem, but I still have to write the code for strongparameters.

My rails server starts but when I access my site I get the following:

"Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Sub"

Sub (like a reddit sub) is a pretty simple class.

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Btw, yes I've searched google, SO, etc. but I can't seem to find a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

O.k. here are the most interesting parts of the Sub class:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Sub < ApplicationRecord

    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    has_many :comments
    attr_accessible :name, :is_private, :is_banned, :is_default, :log_line, :rules, :posted, :nsfw, :is_read_only, :metadata

    validates_presence_of :name, :message => "* required"
    validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 4, :message => "minimum of 4 characters"
    validates :name, length: {maximum: 20}
    validates_format_of :name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$\Z/, :message => "letters, numbers and underscores only"
```

For elasticsearch I have this at the end of my class:

```
def self.search(q)
          __elasticsearch__.search(
            {
             query: {
                multi_match: {
                  query: q, fields: ["name^10", "metadata.log_line^5", 'metadata.sidebar_text^1']
                }
             }
            }
          )`enter code here`
    end
```

So where it loaded is in comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :sub
belongs_to :user

include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

validates :root_comment_id, presence: true
validates :sub_id, presence: true
```

The actual call is in comment.rb model:

Here's the class definition:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord

belongs_to :sub
belongs_to :user

include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

validates :root_comment_id, presence: true
validates :sub_id, presence: true
```

And here's how it's called:

```
sub = Sub.find_by_id(sub_id)
```

Here's the backtrace of the error:

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Sub
rendering 404 in h_controller
  Rendering errors/oops.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered errors/oops.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.erb (31.4ms)

----- Start BACKTRACE -----
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/home/colin/railsworkspace/headcycle/app/admin/sub.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `block in load_file'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_file'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:375:in `block in require_or_load'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:117:in `exclusive'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:543:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/home/colin/railsworkspace/headcycle/app/controllers/h_controller.rb:24:in `set_default_sub_info'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:271:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/home/colin/railsworkspace/headcycle/app/admin/sub.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `block in load_file'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_file'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:375:in `block in require_or_load'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:117:in `exclusive'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:543:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/home/colin/railsworkspace/headcycle/app/controllers/h_controller.rb:24:in `set_default_sub_info'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:271:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
/home/colin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
----- END BACKTRACE -----
```

Comment: Updated my comment

Comment: Where is Sub loaded?  Odds are you have a namespace issue.

Comment: What references Sub? Possible you have something like: `belongs_to :subscription, class_name: Sub` using `belongs_to :subscription, class_name: "Sub"` would help there. Generally speaking, avoid using class constants when you can use a string instead, this helps avoid circular dependencies. Also you might want a more descriptive name. IE: Subscriber, Subscription or even better, UserSupscription or something.

Comment: Updated my comment (see above)

Answer (score 1):

You have the contents of `comment.rb` posted twice. One is inheriting from `ActiveRecord` and the other is inheriting from `ApplicationRecord`.

Not sure if you have 2 `comment.rb` files, but there should only be one, and it should inherit from `ApplicationRecord`